# Does a return economy-class seat between London and San Francisco release 5.28 tonnes of CO2 equivalents?

Tags: climate-change, aviation

I took this [self-survey of CO<sub>2</sub> emissions](https://uba.co2-rechner.de/de_DE/) run by the [German Environment Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umweltbundesamt).

It computes for example that an economy class seat from London to San Francisco and back – about 22 hours flight – accounts for 5.28 tonnes of [CO<sub>2</sub> equivalents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_equivalent) (CO<sub>2</sub>eq or CO<sub>2</sub>e).

> [image: Calculator screenshot]

For comparison,

- the average CO<sub>2</sub>-emission in 2017 per capita has been 9.7 tonnes in Germany according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_carbon_dioxide_emissions) – but that excludes other greenhouse gases.
- The [International Civil Aviation Organization](https://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/CarbonOffset/Pages/default.aspx) gives only 0.762 tonnes CO<sub>2</sub> emission for the same flight. The methodology describes only CO<sub>2</sub> emitted when the fuel is burnt.

> [image: Calculator output]

Is the German Environment Agency's estimate for CO<sub>2</sub>eq from such a return flight reasonable?

Comment: You understand that one site is giving pure CO2 and the other CO2e numbers. You understand that they aren't the same. You understand there is no conflict. So what is the specific claim that you are doubtful about?

Comment: It would make far more sense to ask this on Earth Science, where the domain experts hang out.

Comment: @Oddthinking  My question is whether the Environmental office is exaggerating its interpretation.  If they are correct then the most damaging behavior for the climate I have is flying.  I could save less than 10% by improving my apartment for 30,000$, or by getting rid off my car, but if I stopped flying it would be more than 50% less without any other effort.
And I know people that fly 4 of 5 times as often as I do!!

I have not perceived that other media are presenting flying as the most harmful behavior for the climate a private person can have. Therefore my question.

Comment: @KlausN: "I have not perceived that other media are presenting flying as the most harmful behavior for the climate a private person can have." -- That is strange, because the headlines seem to be full of exactly that discussion recently. Greta Thunberg taking the train to Davos instead of flying prompted the recent round, but it's already been around for a while before that.

Comment: Let's continue any discussion about whether vague questions should be put on hold to  [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95404/discussion-on-question-by-klausn-does-a-return-economy-class-seat-between-london).

Comment: Why don't you ask if the estimate from the *International Civil Aviation Organization* is reasonable? The ICAO surely has a vested interest in claiming that flights aren't too damaging.

Comment: @KlausN: Hmmm https://www.zeit.de/die-antwort/2019-04/flugreisen-klimawandel-co2-emissionen-flugzeuge-konsumverhalten-verantwortung , https://www.spiegel.de/reise/aktuell/oekologischer-fussabdruck-deutsche-urlauber-belasten-weltklima-besonders-stark-a-564498.html , https://www.freitag.de/autoren/der-freitag/hoert-endlich-auf-zu-fliegen , ...

Comment: @DevSolar,@Eric Duminil  Of course I've seen occasionally articles passing by mentioning the bad effects of aviation on climate, but if I compare for example to the car industry that is being pushed by public opinion to rapidly make the switch to electrical engines, or the power production that is changing (in most countries) away from fossil energy and the huge economical efforts that this requires, I'm surprised (assuming the data above is roughly factual) that flying is increasing like this:
https://www.statista.com/statistics/193533/growth-of-global-air-traffic-passenger-demand/

Answer (score 73):

Water vapor is indeed the most important greenhouse effect contributor.<sup>(Ref. 1)</sup>

It is usually not showing up in climate change discussions because mankind basically has no way of directly affecting the amount of water vapor in the air, either positively or negatively, as anything we could or could not do is utterly dwarfed by natural processes. (As opposed to CO<sub>2</sub>.)<sup>(Ref. 2)</sup>

There is one major difference, though. Airplanes. They put significant amounts of CO<sub>2</sub>, and more importantly, water vapor, directly where it has the most significant impact: High up in the atmosphere. And they are the *only* source doing that. When US air traffic was grounded for three days following 9/11, the effects were immediately measurable.<sup>(Ref. 3)</sup>

CarbonIndependent.org [Aviation sources](https://www.carbonindependent.org/sources_aviation.html) elaborates in some detail on how its CO<sub>2</sub> calculator does its calculation, arriving at 250 kg CO<sub>2</sub>e per flight hour (about the same value that the GEA calculator gives you -- 250kg/h * 22h = 5500kg ), then going on to quote Professor David Lee, Director, Centre for Air Transport and the Environment (CATE), Manchester Metropolitan University:

> Whilst it is incorrect to multiply CO2 emissions by the RFI, it is clear from the foregoing that aviation's effects are more than that of CO2. Currently, there is not a suitable climate metric to express the relationship between emissions and radiative effects from aviation in the same way that the global warming potential does but this is an active area of research. Nonetheless, it is clear that aviation imposes other effects on climate which are greater than that implied from simply considering its CO2 emissions alone.

The site then goes on to state (emphasis theirs, but especially note the last line):

> According to this statement, it is incorrect to multiply CO2 emissions by the RFI, but it is also incorrect to ignore them. For the purposes of a calculator, some decision must be taken until further evidence is available, and **the Carbon Independent calculator will for the time being multiply aviation CO2 emissions by a factor of 2.0**. The practical consequences are in fact minor as regards informing people on the easiest way to reduce their carbon footprint; whatever the size of the factor used, the easiest way for most people who fly to reduce their carbon footprint will be to cut back on flying.

---

So, without going into actual number crunching and arguing about the "correct" CO<sub>2</sub>e calculation (which does not exist), the Environment Agency's calculation seem **legit**, and **does** correspond to the broad opinion in climate research.

(1): http://www.geo.utexas.edu/courses/387H/PAPERS/kiehl.pdf

(2): https://www.bpb.de/apuz/30101/klimawandel-einige-fakten

(3): http://www.greenmedinfo.com/blog/artificial-weather-revealed-post-9-11-flight-groundings

---

Further references:

- IPCC, 1999: "[Aviation and the Global Atmosphere](https://www.ipcc.ch/report/aviation-and-the-global-atmosphere-2/)"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95536/discussion-on-answer-by-devsolar-does-a-return-economy-class-seat-between-london).

Answer (score 14):

## Values from *International Civil Aviation Organization* cannot be correct.

Warning : very short calculation ahead. I hope it's alright for *Skeptics*.

One way to check if the results are plausible is to calculate the CO<sub>2</sub> emissions in grams per [passenger-km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_transportation_measurement#Passenger-distance).

- CO<sub>2</sub> emissions for round-trip : `762 kgCO2 / passenger = 762200 gCO2 / passenger`
- Total distance for round-trip is : `2 * 8652km = 17304km`
- Specific CO<sub>2</sub> emissions : `762200 / 17304 = 44 g gCO2 / (km * passenger)`

According to this [IPCC report](https://www.ipcc.ch/site/assets/uploads/2018/02/ipcc_wg3_ar5_chapter8.pdf), the direct CO<sub>2</sub> emissions for passenger aircrafts are between 95 and 250 gCO<sub>2</sub> / (km * passenger) :

[image: ipcc_wg3_ar5_chapter8 figure 8.6]

Source:

> Sims R., R. Schaeffer, F. Creutzig, X. Cruz-Núñez, M. D’Agosto, D.
>   Dimitriu, M. J. Figueroa Meza, L. Fulton, S. Kobayashi, O. Lah, A.
>   McKinnon, P. Newman, M. Ouyang, J. J. Schauer, D. Sperling, and G.
>   Tiwari, 2014: Transport. In: Climate Change 2014: Mitigation of
>   Climate Change. Contribution of Working Group III to the Fifth
>   Assessment Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change
>   [Edenhofer, O., R. Pichs-Madruga, Y. Sokona, E. Farahani, S. Kadner,
>   K. Seyboth, A. Adler, I. Baum, S. Brunner, P. Eickemeier, B. Kriemann,
>   J. Savolainen, S. Schlömer, C. von Stechow, T. Zwickel and J.C. Minx
>   (eds.)]. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, United Kingdom and New
>   York, NY, USA.
>
> Page 610, Figure 8.6

44 gCO<sub>2</sub> / (km * passenger ) would correspond to an efficient train or coach, but seems to be well outside the range of any current airplane.

### How does the ICAO calculate these values?

I have no idea how the ICAO could even come close to 44 gCO<sub>2</sub> / (km * passenger).

Even with those best-case assumptions:

- Most [fuel-efficient plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_aircraft#Medium-haul_flights) (e.g. Boeing 737 MAX-8 or Boeing 787-8).
- [Middle hoal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_aircraft#Flight_distance) flight.
- Plane full of economy-class passengers.
- Only CO<sub>2</sub> is emitted.

it doesn't seem to be possible to get any value under 60 gCO<sub>2</sub> / (km * passenger). Modifying any of the assumptions in order to calculate more realistic values would increase the amount of released CO<sub>2</sub>.

UPDATE : The methodology is described in this [PDF](https://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/CarbonOffset/Documents/Methodology%20ICAO%20Carbon%20Calculator_v10-2017.pdf), I'll try to reproduce the results. (Thanks @Nat!)

Note: I'll investigate the values given by *German Environment Agency* later. Showing that the values from the ICAO are wrong doesn't say anything about those given by the GEA.

Comment: I think the "calculation" you did there is totally acceptable. Basically you just converted the given numbers for comparison with the IPCC report.